# Lotus notes 6.5: Script to check Google webmail sent folder

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

In lotus notes, is there the possibility to check from script if a specific mail is in the sent Google webmail folder ?

Comment: Is Notes set up as an IMAP client for GMail? And how do you expect to identity a specific email?

Comment: i would like to sent programmatically an email from script and after that search for it in "sent" webmail folder. is this possible ? notes must be configured as imap gmail client ?

Comment: No, you don't have to configure Notes as an imap client for gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=en). It's a REST API that works over HTTP, so you can write an agent in Java that makes the necessary HTTP calls. If your code will only run on Windows clients or servers, then you can use LotusScript and make WinHTTP to make the necessary calls.